# Using AspNetCompatibility to run a client project from a WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-services, wcf

I have two projects - a WCF service that provides operations on a database, and an ASP.NET project running AngularJS that acts as a client to the service.

I would like to combine these into a single project. That is, when running the service, the interface (the ASP.NET AngularJS project) should appear.

I have seen some sources saying that AspNetCompatibilityMode can be used to do something like this, but I haven't seen anywhere how to actually specify a client.

Is this the right way to go about doing this? Is there a simpler way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to use AspNetCompatibility. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368071/call-wcf-service-from-javascript-html-within-service

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I assume you want to expose existing WCF service in your ASP.NET web forms/mvc (whatever) type of project. 
Steps:

1) make sure your ASP.NET project references the assembly in which is the WCF service implementation

2) change in your ASP.NET project your global.asax to:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Activation; // from assembly System.ServiceModel.Web
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/Angular", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(WCFNamespace.AngularService)));
}
```

This registers calls starting with the /Service/Angular prefix to be handled by your WCF service.

3) your WCF service should look like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAngularService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Hello", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  [Description("Returns hello world json object")]
  HelloWorld GetHello();
}

[DataContract]
public class HelloWorld
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Note the methods - they should be decorated with `[WebGet]` or `[WebInvoke]` methods since for Angular you want to build RESTfull wcf service. Also serialization/deserialization format is set to json.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
  AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AngularService : IAngularService
{
  public HelloWorld GetHello()
  {
    return new HelloWorld { Message = "Hello from WCF. Time is: " +
      DateTime.Now.ToString() };
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to get json object if you type /Services/Angular/Hello into browser.

And finally as you've noted the WCF contract implementation (in this case class AngularService) has to be marked with attribute `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements]` so the IIS can host it under ASP.NET web forms/MVC project.

Disclaimer: this is very naive implementation, in real world you probably would want to catch & log exceptions that happen in service and return them to client in form of json.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "The type or namespace name 'WebServiceHostFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)" I added System.ServiceModel.Activation to the project references and added "using System.ServiceModel.Activation" to Global.asax. Do I need to add something to Web.config as well?

Comment: Apparently I need to use ServiceHostFactory. I added the other stuff; what's the full URL that I should be able to go to? I've tried http://localhost:port/AngularService.svc/Services/Angular/Hello, but got the error "Server Error in '/' Application"

Comment: @Evan - I really meant WebServiceHostFactory :) I've edited the answer to highlight assembly and namespace.